# How to use jest to test blocks in Meteor.methods

Tags: javascript, meteor, jestjs, ts-jest

I am writing jest test to my meteor project. I am trying to test codes in the Meteor.methods, but I am not sure how to do it with Jest.

On the server side (which is also main.js), the code snippets look like something bellow,

```
Meteor.methods({
        'shops.get': () => { return ShopList.find({}).fetch();},
)};
```

in main.test.js, I wrote something like

```
describe('methods', () => {
    let shops=[];
    beforeEach(() => {
    Meteor.call('shops.get',(e,r)=>{
      if(!e) shops=r;
    });
 });
});
```

But an error occurs:

```
    ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined
```

I've read a an article mentioning faking meteor in a file.(https://blog.meteor.com/real-world-unit-tests-with-meteor-and-jest-3d557e84e84a), but I am not sure in this way how to resolve symbols like Meteor.call or Meteor.methods.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html for information on testing.

This is an integration test, as you are testing database functions, you should use Meteor to run the tests, as otherwise you have a lot of mocking to do, and then you don't prove much except your mocks work as expected.

So use the `meteor test` command, with the appropriate driver, such as https://atmospherejs.com/meteortesting/mocha - it's not jest, but it will give you the result you want.

If you need more information, I can provide you with some sample code if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but because I don't intend to so tightly couple meteor related things with the tests, I will seriously consider to use other frameworks to replace meteor. But anyway thanks again for this reply.

Comment: That's fine, and probably what your strategy could be is to split up the testing, anything that is database heavy could use meteor testing, and anything that is pure processing calculations can be done using other tools. It's normal to use different tools for each testing aspect)